# Incorrect syntax due SQL query execution

Tags: mysql, sql, ado.net

I'm trying to execute next query

```
DECLARE @ponumber varchar(50)
DECLARE @gcas varchar(50)
SET @ponumber = '3864_ab03963'
SET @gcas = '81332119.'
EXEC(N'SELECT * FROM tCleanOrderTracking_prod 
       WHERE [PO number] = ' + @ponumber + ' AND [GCAS] = ' + @gcas)
```

And I've got an error message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '_ab03963'.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing is [very dangerous](http://xkcd.com/327/). You should use [prepared statements with parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you missed `'` near @gcas.

```
DECLARE @ponumber varchar(50)
DECLARE @gcas varchar(50)
SET @ponumber = '3864_ab03963'
SET @gcas = '81332119.'
EXEC(N'SELECT * FROM tCleanOrderTracking_prod 
       WHERE [PO number] = ' + @ponumber + ' AND [GCAS] = ' + @gcas + ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the single quote after the @gcas parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose with quotes your all string parameters, For example:

`quote(@gcas)` instead of simple `@gcas`